# Verbatim PHP code works on current, live site, but not new site (local or live)

Tags: php, verbatim

> MySQL
>
> Server: mysql.mysite.com via TCP/IP Server version: 5.1.56-log
>   Protocol version: 10 User: username@__.dreamhost.com MySQL charset:
>   UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
>
> Web server
>
> Apache MySQL client version: 5.1.66 PHP extension: mysql
>
> phpMyAdmin
>
> Version information: 3.3.10.4

I am at wits end right now. The exact code is currently working on the live site, but will not work for the new site I am designing.

```
<table>
    <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

    <th>###</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Mileage</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
<?

  $host = "mysql.mysite.com";
  $user = "username";
  $pass = "password";
  $dbname = "database";

  $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");
  mysql_select_db($dbname);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE sold='n' ORDER BY year DESC";

  $query = mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

    echo "<tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>",$row['year'],"</td>
      <td>",$row['make'],"</td>
      <td>",$row['model'],"</td>
      <td>",$row['dscrpt'],"</td>
      <td>",$row['miles'],"</td>
      <td>",'$',$row['price'],"</td>
      </tr>";
  }
  ?> 
</table>
```

I am receiving the following results on the site, both locally & when loaded on the server:

> "); mysql_select_db($dbname); $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE
>   sold='n' ORDER BY year DESC"; $query = mysql_query($sql); while ($row
>   = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { echo ""; } ?>
>
> #### Year    Make    Model   Description Mileage Price ",$row['year'],"  ",$row['make'],"    ",$row['model'],"   ",$row['dscrpt'],"  ",$row['miles'],"   ",'$',$row['price'],"

I tried a few other ways including mysqli approach, but they all yield the same results. Nothing has changed with the any of the connections and the current connection/web page still returns data. I'm going crazy looking over the code and using different code with the same results.

Comment: Your new site probably has short open tags disabled. Use `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: I actually noticed that after posting and tried the <?php instead of <?, but I am getting the same results

Comment: Or your new site isn't parsing PHP at all.

Comment: wow.. okay. I figured it out. I had to change the file extension to PHP from HTML. I tested the PHP locally and it was only displaying the code and I must not have tested it on the server. Once I loaded it to the server and changed the extension to PHP, it was displaying the rows. I spent way too much time trying to figure that out than I should have.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<?php` instead of the short open tag `<?`.

Comment: Short open tags can still be useful for when you're outputting text, e.g. `<?= 'hello world' ?>'. You can turn them on from php.ini, short_open_tag option (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Comment: Or just use PHP 5.4 where `<?=` is always available, regardless of any settings.

Comment: I actually noticed that after posting and tried the <?php instead of <?, but I am getting the same results

Comment: @khaos Is PHP enabled at all?

Comment: Okay so somewhere along the way of me testing locally and on the server, I must have changed the file extension to HTML. PHP wasn't displaying locally and I must have changed the extension. I feel really horrible that it took me that long to figure it out. But I did find other things within the code to improve on as well. Thanks for the help!